# Store images in prestashop from URL

Tags: image, url, smarty, store, prestashop

I have a web service that is called to get products for a prestashop project. The web service is returning information about the product and also each product have a link representing the image of the product. I know that prestashop stores images into "img/p/id/picture.ext", but I want to find a solution to store that URL in the database and output everywhere in template files that picture. I want to know if there is a module for this, or how should I solve this the fastest way ? Thank you guys!

Comment: Is the PrestaShop product id the same as the web service product id? Is it possible to generate the product image URL from the web service product id?

Comment: No, I cannot. I was thinking to modify the default behavior of prestashop but it is too complicated and time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to save the product image URL in an unused product field (e.g., Reference) and modify the `src` attribute of the product image `img` tag in `product.tpl`:

```
<img src="{$product->reference}">
```

Comment: Reference is not used? Then I will definetly use this as a solution to my problem. Thank you very much!